# RSA cryptosystem

Tags: security, cryptography, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

Hi i am trying to set up an RSA cryptosystem i have all the values except d selected prime numbers: `p=1889`, `q=2003`, `n=3783667`, `phi=3779776`, `e= 61`

i got stuck finding d could anyone help me to figure it out?

Setting up an RSA cryptosystem

- Two large distinct prime numbers `p` and `q` are selected, and `n = pq` and `Φ(n) = (p − 1)(q − 1)` are calculated.
- An integer `e` is selected such that `gcd(Φ(n), e) = 1` and the multiplicative inverse `d = e^(−1)` in `ZΦ(n)` is calculated, i.e.

  ed ≡ 1 (mod Φ(n)).
- The numbers `p`, `q`, and `Φ(n)`, are then discarded.
- The pair `(e, n)` is published as the public encryption key
- The number `d` is the secret decryption key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/rsa/rsa.html) the algo, step by step, including finding *d*.
*m* from the article is your *Φ(n)*.
Now, you try to find a *d = (1 + nm) / e*, working through values of *n* until an integer solution for *e* is found.

Edit:
[Here](http://www.math.mtu.edu/mathlab/COURSES/holt/dnt/phi4.html) you'll find a more detailed explanation of the whole algorithm.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I managed to find d=1487125. Now I am struggling to find the Block size!!! Do you have any idea?

Comment: Edited with a new link, with some more detailed explanation and Graphical demonstrations of the different stages, including finding the block size.